# MVC Partial Views in Site.Master

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to render a partial view in my Site.Master file but I keep on getting an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).  If I access the view directly, I get the info that I need, but if I access the Index View from the HomeController, I get an error.    The partial view will display the logged in user, department, and role.  This is my code.

Controllers Folder
-HomeController.cs
-UsersController.cs

```
Models
-Repository Folder
  - UersRepository.cs
-Repository Interface Folder
  - IUsers.cs
-Service Folder
  - UsersService.cs
  - IUserService.cs
-Validation Folder
  - IValidationDictionary
  - ModelStateWrapper
```

The view that I'm trying to partially render is called LoginInfo.ascx and it's located in the Shared Folder.

LoginInfo.cs Code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Users>>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="TimeAttendanceMVC.Models"%>




<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            UserName
        </th>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th>
            UserType
        </th>

    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserType) %>
        </td>

    </tr>
<% } %>

</table>
```

Site.Master Code:

```
   <% Html.RenderPartial("LoginInfo"); %>
```

UserController.cs

```
 public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        //
        private IUsersService _service;

        //==============================================================================
        //==============================================================================
        public UsersController()
        {
          _service = new UsersService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));
         }

        public UsersController(IUsersService service)
        {
            _service = service; 
        }

        //==============================================================================
        //==============================================================================
        // GET: /Employee/
        //==============================================================================
        //==============================================================================
        // GET: /Employee/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = _service.Return_UserName_Dept();
            return View("LoginInfo", model);
        }

    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //var model = _service.Return_UserName_Dept();
            //return View(model);
            return View();

        }
```

With the code above, I get an error.  If I un-comment the 2 lines in my HomeController and I pass the model to the View, then it works fine.  But my HomeController will need a different model, so how will I pass 2 models to the View?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I'm still learning MVC right now so I'm not that good at this. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `RenderPartial` renders the view directly, inheriting the parent's model.

You should call `RenderAction` instead to render a child action so that the action can pass the correct model to the partial view.

Comment: I changed my code to the following: <% Html.RenderAction("LoginInfo"); %> but I now get a different error: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: Look at the InnerException to find the problem.  You probably forgot to specify the controller name.

Comment: The InnerException says: {"A public action method 'LoginInfo' was not found on controller 'TimeAttendanceMVC.Controllers.HomeController'."}.  I'm not sure how to fix this.  Am I supposed to add a new LoginInfo action to my HomeController as well?  This action is present in my UsersController.

Comment: No; you're supposed to add `, "Users"` to the `RenderAction` call to specify the controller.

Comment: Ok.  I'm using this now:   <% Html.RenderAction("LoginInfo", "Users"); %> but I still get the error: {"A public action method 'LoginInfo' was not found on controller 'TimeAttendanceMVC.Controllers.UsersController'."}

Comment: Got it.  I actually didn't have LoginInfo as an action.  I had an Index action that called this: return View("LoginInfo", model);  I created a new LoginInfo action and now it works.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller is able to pass a single Model to the View for rendering.  Rather than attempting to have two models, or to call two Action Methods in a request with RenderAction, have you considered creating a parent ViewModel type?

```
// This model is passed to your view for rendering
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // This property is passed as the model to your partial view
    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel(); // _service.GetIndexViewModel();
    model.UserInfo = _service.Return_UserName_Dept();;
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your View, you would do something like:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginInfo", Model.UserInfo); %>
```

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure how to do that or what a parent ViewModel is.  Still very new at this and I'm just trying to get my first MVC application started.

Comment: I updated my answer.  By parent ViewModel, I mean that the single model that your Controller passes to the View for rendering includes a child property which acts as the model for the partial view.  In the case above you'll see MyViewModel includes a UserInfo property which is passed to the UserInfo partial.  Hope this helps!